# AddClass after removeClass don't work in kendo tree view when select same node

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-treeview

Hello i have a kendoTreeView and i want that the click in the same selected node trigger an action so in the event change i used this code

```
change : function(e) {

                        $("#DT-DICT-treeview").data("kendoTreeView").select()
                                            .find("span.k-state-selected")
                                            .removeClass("k-state-selected");
                                }
```

it work  fine but the background of the selected node became transparent 
so i added a class that have the same CSS of selected node and added on evry change . It work for the first select but in seconde won't work.
 Any help please

here is an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waelkat/syg9746k/)

step to make this issue

1) select node DT1 : it become in blue

2) select node DT2 : DT1 become normal DT2 become in blue

3) select node DT1 : don't work any more

any help please

Comment: You are breaking the behavior of the plugin by manually removing the `k-state-selected` class. Override the styling and leave *their* selection class alone :)

Comment: Kendo uses those classes in their functionaility. Have a look at their documentation for 'removing' the class/selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are breaking the behavior of the plugin by manually removing the `k-state-selected` class. Override the styling and leave *their* selection class alone :)

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/syg9746k/1/

e.g. Custom style to target the specific additional class:

```
.k-treeview .k-in.k-state-selected.k-selected-treeView-active {
    background-color: #428bca;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Use Chrome to see the specific selectors used for `border`, `hover` etc on the tree nodes and add you own CSS styles that include `.k-selected-treeView-active` as well, so that they are more specific.

Comment: I remove the `k-state-selected` class because when i click in same selected node the event don't trigger any more for example click on DT1 there is an alert click another time on it the alert don't show any more .

I remove k-state-selected class to trigger event when i click in the same selected node

Comment: If you click "the same selected node" you will not get a Kendo `change` as the selection is not changing. Trying to hack that behavior from styles on the outside is going to have problems. The solution to your immediate problem (the blue missing) is styling (as above), but you need to expand the question with more details about the selection issue. Perhaps a new question to cover that?